# Rendering multiple (hundreds or even thousands) web-components

Tags: javascript, html, performance, web-component

The problem I am facing is that rendering a lot of web-components is slow. Scripting takes around 1,5s and then another 3s for rendering (mostly Layout + Recalculate styles) for ~5k elements, I plan to put much more than that into the DOM. My script to prepare those Elements takes around 100-200ms, the rest comes from `constructor` and other callbacks.
For normal HTML Elements a perf gain can be achieved with [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), where you basically prepare a batch of elements, and only when you're done you attach them to the DOM.
Unfortunately, each web-component will call its `constructor` and other callbacks like `connectedCallback`, `attributeChangedCallback` etc. When having a lot of such components it's not really optimal.

Is there a way to "prerender" web-components before inserting them into the DOM?

I've tried to put them inside `template` elements and clone the contents, but the constructor is still called for each instance of `my-component`. One thing that did improve the performance is putting content that is attached to the shadow DOM inside a template outside of component and cloning it instead of using `this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).innerHTML=...`, but that's not enough.

Comment: Probably find this article of interest https://medium.com/@azizhk/building-an-async-react-renderer-with-diffing-in-web-worker-f3be07f16d90

Comment: Perhaps "pretender" is the exact opposite of where you should be thinking. The solution is to "postrender" - In other words, build the DOM asynchronously a bit a time _as it is needed_ (or just before if that can be anticipated).

Comment: If you defer the DOM creation (from a template, defined outside the element definition) to the `connectedCallback` method, rather than the `constructor` then it will only run when the component is added to the DOM rather than when you create the element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to render all ~5k elements at once? You will face performance problems rendering that many elements in the DOM independently of if you manage to pre-initialize the components in memory.

A common technique for this scenario is to use a technique called "windowing" or "lazy rendering": the idea is to render only a small subset of your components at any given time depending on what's on the user viewport.

After a very quick search, I didn't find a library for web-components that implements this, but for reference in React you have [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) and in Vue [vue-windowing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-windowing)